# Post-build step in QBS

Tags: build, qbs, nrf51

I'm trying to convert the nRF51822 (an Arm Cortex microcontroller) build process from `Make` to `QBS`. I've got the compilation process working ok (lots of hard-coded paths but I'll fix that later). However, the final step is to use `objcopy` to convert the `.out` file produced by the linker to a `.hex` file. I can't work out how to get my rule to run other than by making another `Application` like this (which doesn't work very well):

```
import qbs
import qbs.FileInfo

Project {
    CppApplication {
        type: "application" // To suppress bundle generation on Mac

        name: "nrf51_template"

        files: ["main.cpp",
            "nrf51822/Source/nrf_delay/nrf_delay.c"]

        Group {
            name: "Startup files"
            files: ["nrf51822/Source/Templates/system_" + deviceSeries + ".c",
            "nrf51822/Source/Templates/gcc/gcc_startup_" + deviceSeries + ".s"]
        }


        // The chip variant can be:
        //
        // "xxaa": The 256 kB version
        // "xxbb": The 128 kB version
        //
        // RFduino is xxaa.
        property string deviceVariant: "xxaa"

        // Must be "nrf51"
        property string deviceSeries: "nrf51"

        // The softdevice (radio firmware) to use. Can be:
        //
        // "": For no radio.
        // "s110": For BLE slave/peripheral
        // "s120": For BLE host/central
        // "s130": For BLE central and peripheral
        property string softDevice: "s110"

        // Must be cortex-m0
        property string cpu: "cortex-m0"

        cpp.includePaths: ["nrf51822/Include", "nrf51822/Include/gcc"]
        cpp.compilerName: ["arm-none-eabi-g++.exe"]
        cpp.compilerPath: ["C:/Program Files/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/4.8 2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++.exe"]
        cpp.linkerName: ["arm-none-eabi-g++.exe"]
        cpp.linkerPath: ["C:/Program Files/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/4.8 2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++.exe"]

        cpp.cxxFlags: ["-mcpu=" + cpu, "-mthumb", "-mabi=aapcs", "--std=c++11", "-mfloat-abi=soft"]
        cpp.linkerFlags: ["-L\"C:/Program Files/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/4.8 2014q1/arm-none-eabi/lib/armv6-m\"",
            "-L\"C:/Program Files/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/4.8 2014q1/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.3/armv6-m\"",
            "-Xlinker",
            "-Map=C:/Users/thutt/nRF51_Template/output_filename.map",
            "-mcpu=" + cpu,
            "-mthumb",
            "-mabi=aapcs",
            "-L", "C:/Users/thutt/nRF51_Template/nrf51822/Source/templates/gcc/",
            "-Tgcc_" + deviceSeries + "_" + softDevice + "_" + deviceVariant + ".ld"]

        cpp.defines: ["BOARD_PCA10001", "NRF51"]

        // Suppresses -m32 compiler option.
        cpp.architecture: "arm"

        // Suppress windows definitions and compiler options.
        cpp.minimumWindowsVersion: undefined

        cpp.executableSuffix: ".out"

        // To flash:

        // nrfjprog --reset --program $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).hex

    }

    Application {
        name: "nrf51_template_hex"

        Group {
            files: "C:/Users/thutt/nRF51_Template-build/qtc_Desktop2-debug/nrf51_template.out"
            fileTags: ["out"]
        }

        Depends {
            name: "nrf51_template"
        }


        Rule {
            id: hex
            inputs: ["out"]

            Artifact {
                fileTags: ["application"]
                fileName: ".obj/" + product.name + "/" + input.baseDir + "/" + input.fileName + ".hex"
            }

            prepare: {
    //          var compilerPath = ModUtils.moduleProperty(product, "compilerPath");

                var objCopyPath = "C:/Program Files/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/4.8 2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-objcopy.exe";
                var args = ["-O", "ihex", input.filePath, output.filePath];
                var cmd = new Command(objCopyPath, args);

                cmd.description = "converting to hex: " + FileInfo.fileName(input.filePath);
                cmd.highlight = "linker";
                return cmd;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to have a post-link step in the `CppApplication` instead of two `Application`s like this? Am I better off defining a totally new `Application` with my own `Rule`s for compilation and linking?

Also bonus question, is it possible to specify the "run" executable in the QBS file so that when I click run in QtCreator it actually runs nrfjprog.exe and flashes the code to the chip? (You can do this in the IDE but I'd prefer to be able to do it in the QBS file.)

Comment: Great idea, I'm meaning to try QBS for some MCU project too! Ping me on Twitter if you wanna chat about this ;)

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out, the final targets are determined by the `type:` line in the `Application` so just change it to this:

```
import qbs
import qbs.FileInfo

Project {
    CppApplication {

        // The filetag to generate.
        type: "hex"

        name: "nrf51_template"

        files: ["main.cpp",
            "SaneSPI.cpp",
            "SaneSPI.h",
            "Timer.cpp",
            "Timer.h",
            "Delay.cpp",
            "Delay.h",
            "GPIO.cpp",
            "GPIO.h"]

        Group {
            name: "Startup files"
            files: ["nrf51822/Source/Templates/system_" + deviceSeries + ".c",
            "nrf51822/Source/Templates/gcc/gcc_startup_" + deviceSeries + ".s"]
        }


        // The chip variant can be:
        //
        // "xxaa": The 256 kB version
        // "xxbb": The 128 kB version
        //
        // RFduino is xxaa.
        property string deviceVariant: "xxaa"

        // Must be "nrf51"
        property string deviceSeries: "nrf51"

        // The softdevice (radio firmware) to use. Can be:
        //
        // "": For no radio.
        // "s110": For BLE slave/peripheral
        // "s120": For BLE host/central
        // "s130": For BLE central and peripheral
        property string softDevice: "s110"

        // Must be cortex-m0
        property string cpu: "cortex-m0"

        cpp.includePaths: ["nrf51822/Include",
            "nrf51822/Include/gcc",
            "nrf51822/Include/" + softDevice]
        cpp.compilerName: ["arm-none-eabi-g++.exe"]
        cpp.compilerPath: ["C:/Program Files/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/4.8 2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++.exe"]
        cpp.linkerName: ["arm-none-eabi-g++.exe"]
        cpp.linkerPath: ["C:/Program Files/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/4.8 2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++.exe"]

        cpp.cxxFlags: ["-mcpu=" + cpu, "-mthumb", "-mabi=aapcs", "--std=c++11", "-mfloat-abi=soft"]
        cpp.linkerFlags: ["-L\"C:/Program Files/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/4.8 2014q1/arm-none-eabi/lib/armv6-m\"",
            "-L\"C:/Program Files/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/4.8 2014q1/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.3/armv6-m\"",
            "-Xlinker",
            "-Map=C:/Users/thutt/nRF51_Template/output_filename.map",
            "-mcpu=" + cpu,
            "-mthumb",
            "-mabi=aapcs",
            "-L", "C:/Users/thutt/nRF51_Template/nrf51822/Source/templates/gcc/",
            "-Tgcc_" + deviceSeries + "_" + softDevice + "_" + deviceVariant + ".ld"]

        cpp.defines: ["BOARD_PCA10001", "NRF51"]

        // Suppresses -m32 compiler option.
        cpp.architecture: "arm"

        // Suppress windows definitions and compiler options.
        cpp.minimumWindowsVersion: undefined

        cpp.executableSuffix: ".out"

        Rule {
            id: hex
            inputs: ["application"]

            Artifact {
                fileTags: ["hex"]
                fileName: ".obj/" + product.name + "/" + input.baseDir + "/" + input.fileName + ".hex"
            }

            prepare: {
    //          var compilerPath = ModUtils.moduleProperty(product, "compilerPath");

                var objCopyPath = "C:/Program Files/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/4.8 2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-objcopy.exe";
                var args = ["-O", "ihex", input.filePath, output.filePath];
                var cmd = new Command(objCopyPath, args);

                cmd.description = "converting to hex: " + FileInfo.fileName(input.filePath);
                cmd.highlight = "linker";
                return cmd;
            }
        }

        // To flash:

        // nrfjprog --reset --program $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).hex

    }
}
```